# Chicago intext citation for different references on same sentence

Tags: citations

Given a sentence.

> We can use A,B,C or other methods.

How would each of A,B and C be cited.

like this

> We can use A (Citation A),B (Citation B),C (Citation C) or other methods

or this

> We can use A,B,C (Citation A; Citation B; Citation C) or other methods.

or

> We can use A,B,C ((Citation A), (Citation B) and (Citation C)) or other methods.

Comment: Have you looked at the Chicago book or website? What did you find?

Comment: Ive looked around and the closest i have found is multiple citation for one topic, in the sentence (2nd method here). but that doesnt exactly fit here. as each of the mentioned items is different and has different citation.

Answer (score 1):

I think

the 1st way is OK

the 2nd way is better (especially if there are exactly three methods and three citations), because it is more uncluttered

the 3rd way is wrong, because it has too many brackets.

Comment: i went with 1 for now as it seemed the least ambiguous and yes there are exactly 3 citatations

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like

> We can use A,B,C (respectively Citation A; Citation B; Citation C) or other
> methods.